# Add a single quote after and before a comma

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi I am trying to insert a single quote (') after and before a comma in my text string.

E.g. `ptprptitrklgfd','sofpdsofksdlfd','weroweprewfmvrewrewrieowrioewirew','`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions, just do a standard search and replace to replace `,` with `','`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Click on "Replace"
- `,` in the first field
- `','` in the second field
- Click on "Replace all"

Edit: if you only want to do a certain string, highlight it and click on the "In Selection" checkbox before clicking Replace All